# How to use Ctrl+Shift+R in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  is the shortcut key for a hard reload and refresh. How can I apply this shortcut in selenium Java?

I tried with following code but could not get the results.

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SHIFT,"r");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

I also tried with action class. But it is not working.

PS: No errors were displayed. But, it does not perform the action and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is working.

Comment: Try with Robot class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Robot` class as an alternative to perform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

import below packages :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

And use below code :

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// press key Ctrl+Shift+r
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
// relase key Ctrl+Shift+r
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.delay(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

**Important Note:** Don't forget to release all the key (`keyRelease`) what you have used in `keyPress` to perform your action using `Robot` class, else you may observe unexpected keyboard behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To refresh and reload *WebPage* you can simulate the usage of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> through:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```